# How to create a list item with two-column content without a "phantom" line?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to create a list where each row has a number indicating the row (e.g., "1" for the first row, "2" for the second row, etc.), one or more icons (e.g., delete, edit, etc.) immediately to the right of the number, and then block of text after that.  See [table at the bottom of this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbeall/93cZs/4/) for illustration of this.

The part that's tripping me up is the wrapping of the text after the icons. I want it to visually be three columns (one column for number, one for the icons, and one for the text), so that when the text wraps, it does not wrap underneath the icons.

I initially tried two div blocks as the li content, both divs left-floated and with explicit widths set, but what I discovered is that a "phantom" empty line then appears in the list item. See list item #1 below and in fiddle.

If I don't apply a clearfix to the list item, then the "phantom" line disappears, but the list item label (i.e., the number) appears after the list item contents, and the background color on the list item isn't applied to all children--something I want. See list item #2 below and in fiddle.

The next thing I thought about trying was putting the entire contents of the list item in a two-column table, but that results in the same behavior as #1. See list item #3 below and in fiddle.

I could accomplish this with a three-column table (as shown in my fiddle), but I want to take advantage of the browsers ability to number lielements in a list automatically. This is so I can insert and delete li elements via JavaScript and not have to worry about re-numbering everything manually.  If I used a table, I would need to manually insert the appropriate number on every row, and keep track of it as items were added and removed from the table.

Here's some sample code demonstrating the issue, and the [link to the fiddle for this code](http://jsfiddle.net/jbeall/93cZs/4/).

```
#some-list {
    width: 200px;
}

#some-list li{
    list-style-type: decimal;
    background-color: #FAFAD2;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#some-list li div {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
}

.row-icons{
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
}
.row-title {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

.visual-example {
    width: 250px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.visual-example td {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.icons-cell, .row-title-cell {
    background-color: #FAFAD2;
}
.icons-cell {
    width: 30px;
}

/* For modern browsers */
.container:before,
.container:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.container:after {
    clear:both;
}
/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
.container {
    zoom:1;
}

<ol id='some-list'>
   <li class='container'>
       <div class='row-icons'>
           <img src='https://cdn.nexternal.com/Shared/StoreFront/Images/delete.gif' alt='delete' />
           <img src='https://cdn.nexternal.com/Shared/StoreFront/Images/pencil.gif' alt='edit' />
       </div>
       <div class='row-title'>A lengthy description of this row, it doesn't quite fit on one line.  Notice the "phantom" line above this text.</div>
    </li>

   <li>
       <div class='row-icons'>
           <img src='https://cdn.nexternal.com/Shared/StoreFront/Images/delete.gif' alt='delete' />
           <img src='https://cdn.nexternal.com/Shared/StoreFront/Images/pencil.gif' alt='edit' />
       </div>
       <div class='row-title'>A lengthy description of this row, it doesn't quite fit on one line. No clearfix, and notice the rendering of the number looks bad, and the background color is only applied to the first line.</div>
    </li>

   <li>
       <table><tr>
           <td>
               <img src='https://cdn.nexternal.com/Shared/StoreFront/Images/delete.gif' alt='delete' />
               <img src='https://cdn.nexternal.com/Shared/StoreFront/Images/pencil.gif' alt='edit' />
           </td>
           <td>
               A lengthy description of this row, it doesn't quite fit on one line.  Same problem as #1, although no clearfix and no floating applied.
           </td>
       </tr></table>
    </li>
</ol>


<p style='clear: both; padding-top: 30px;'>This is what I'm trying to accomplish</p>
<table class='visual-example'>
    <tr>
        <td class='list-style-type-cell'>1</td>
        <td class='icons-cell'>
            <img src='https://cdn.nexternal.com/Shared/StoreFront/Images/delete.gif' alt='delete' />
            <img src='https://cdn.nexternal.com/Shared/StoreFront/Images/pencil.gif' alt='edit' />
        </td>
        <td class='row-title-cell'>
            A lengthy description of this row, it doesn't quite fit on one line.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using list style property in ol as

```
list-style: inside decimal;
```

Comment: Doesn't appreciably change things.  Here's an updated fiddle with that, so you can see for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/jbeall/93cZs/5/  It is slightly different, but not "right".

Comment: or else use the foreground images as background images

Answer (score 0):

Both your approaches - with DIV and with Table are now working.
Have a look at :

http://jsfiddle.net/93cZs/6/

Code changes:

```
Floats to your div and table
Modification to how you are displaying your decimals
Modification of how you are handling images
```